# Determine if WebBrowser Successfully loaded a page

Tags: c#, uri, webbrowser-control

Is there an easy way to find out if a WPF WebBrowser successfully loaded a page? I was able to figure out a workaround for HTML documents. It requires that I add the MSHTML reference to my DLL. I've been testing the code by trying to load "http://www.google.m". I used a non-existant website on purpose.

```
        Browser.LoadCompleted += HandleLoaded;
        private void HandleLoaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
           if (_browser.Document is mshtml.HTMLDocument doc)
            {
                if (doc.title == "Navigation Canceled")
                { HandleInvalidAddress(); }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read the [ReadyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.readystate). It returns a [WebBrowserReadyState value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowserreadystate). You're looking for "Complete".

Comment: ReadyState in not available in WPF. It looks like it would work for Forms though.

Comment: @CBFT Oh, I kind of made the assumption that you could get the object from the WPF one. I'm out of ideas then, but you could potentially use CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)